# create a php table with the name of a session

Tags: php, mysql, windows, session

i can't find the answer for this anywhere. but very simply i have a create table and a saved session. i need that session to be the table name. this is shown below. i have struggled with this and have tried to find an answer everywhere.

below is the create msql table. the session is $id and below is what i have tried so far.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $id . " (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";
```

this is the page in context (updated)

```html
<?php
//header("Location:all_games/myscorenum.php");
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "score";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

session_start();
$id=$_SESSION['id'];

echo"$id";


 $sql = "CREATE TABLE '" . $id . "' (
   id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50),
     reg_date TIMESTAMP
   ) ";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving? Is $id not set?

Comment: use session_name() for the name

Comment: here @Alexei Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''42' ( id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, first name VARCHAR(30) NOT' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this query

```
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE '. $id .' (
   id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50),
     reg_date TIMESTAMP
   ) ";
```

Comment: i can echo the session fine but not on the create table

Comment: this is the error     Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''42' ( id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, first name VARCHAR(30) NOT' at line 1

Comment: its still coming up with this ____  Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''43' ( id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, firstname VARCHAR(3' at line 1

Comment: Also please send you session value?

Comment: the session value is a number which is given on the page before it

Comment: if session value is number then you may use this query for testing

       $sql = "CREATE TABLE 10 (
       id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(50),
         reg_date TIMESTAMP
       ) ";

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [session ID](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) (`session_id()`):

```
$id = session_id();
if (!empty($id) {
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $id . " (
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
            firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            email VARCHAR(50),
            reg_date TIMESTAMP
    )";
}
```

And actually *why* do you need it to be the name of the table?

Comment: this is the error      Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''42' ( id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT' at line 1